# tensorflow repeated running of fully connected model

Tags: python-2.7, queue, tensorflow

*Question:*

How can I "rerun" tensorflow code that depends on queues? Is the best way really to close the session, build the model again, load variables and run?

*Motivation:*

In a [standing unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232417/tensorflow-fully-connected-control-flow-per-n-epoch-summary/38232535#38232535) I asked how in a fully connected model one could interleave actions (such as generating cumulative summaries, calc AUC on test data, etc.) with training that reads data from tensorflow TFRecords files and tf.Queues.

For example, tf.train.string_input_producer returns a filename_queue. As part of the constructor it takes a "num_epochs" arg. Instead of setting "num_epochs" to 100, I'm thinking to just set "num_epochs" to "2" to generate summaries every other epoch. This requires running the same code 50 times, hence the need for an efficient answer to above.

Comment: Since you are calling session.run, you can calculate the summaries between session.run calls, no?  In this case there's no need to recreate the sessoin & graph.

You may also want to consider some of the streaming summaries available in [tf.contrib.metrics](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a06837336bc29cb797c5be5605cb6188857768c/tensorflow/contrib/metrics/__init__.py) such as streaming_auc, streaming_accuracy, streaming_*_at_k, ... etc

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The first issue that motivates this question is that I can't switch from train-data queues to test-data queues without waiting for the former to be exhausted and throw RangeError.

The issue this question addresses is that after the train queue is exhausted, it is closed "for good". Threads are closed, the coordinator is halted, the queue is closed. This is default behavior, and it's difficult to go back to training without "starting over".

The question I've been getting at is how best to alternate between train/test feeds while gathering statistics the meantime

Comment: Can't you start two threads or two processes, both talking to the same session?  If two threads, you have access to the session object.  If two processes, you can launch a GRPC server and connect to it from both processes.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. My intuition tells me that's a little over my head for now. Could you point me to a working example?
Also, I was recently given the suggestion to use QueueBase.from_list, which I might try. That way you can have one queue that alternates between train and test queues.

Comment: Looking over it somemore, queuebase.from_list doesn't quite seem to work.  I still need a way of "coming back" to the (previously-exhausted) train queue after the test queue